# Is format also used to parse input string?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the datepicker popup with `format='dd.MM.yyyy'`. However, if the user is not using the datepicker, but instead enters the date by himself, the date is parsed as `MM.dd.yyyy`, i.e. month and day are mixed up.

The same thing can be done in the official [demo page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

1. Scroll down to datepicker
2. Select `dd.MM.yyyy` as format in the format drop down
3. Enter `01.02.2014` in the "popup" field above - the resulting date will be Jan 2nd, not Feb 1st.

Is there any way to get the right behavior? Or is this a bug?